# Wordpress - different custom link per each featured image

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new on Stack overflow.
First of all thanks to all community for accepting my subscription.
I have a little issue with a site that I'm building:

http://gianfabiopezzolla.com/centocelleonline.it

In the front page I have a Mansory for lasts posts that show the feautured image and the title.

I want set a custom link to different page (E.g. First featured image -> contact-page ) per every each feautured image.

I've tried with the code below, but seems doesn't work:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(the_id_of_post); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="item-sizer">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( get_theme_mod( 'index_feat_image' ) != 1 ) ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(the_id_of_page); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('oria-small-thumb'); ?></a>        
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <header class="entry-header blog-entry-header">
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink(the_id_of_page) ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

</div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Someone can Help me please?

Comment: Hi, try with `get_permalink($Id)` or `get_page_link($id)` insted `the_permalink()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but it seems doesn't work. If I replace get_page_link($id) or get_permalink($id) the link return the homepage and not the page that I want to display.

Comment: Parameter `the_id_of_page` should be ID of page You want to display, not home page id.

Comment: Yes you'r right. In fact inside the parentheses I've written the page id (in my case '2'), but the code still not working. The link return to home-page by default. I will, however, that for every single featured image displayed, I can set a different custom link that goes on a different page. I hope I'm explaining well. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you use get_permalink like this it will do

```
$link = get_the_permalink($page_id); 
<div class="entry-thumb">
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"> title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('oria-small-thumb'); ?></a>        
</div>
```

Where `$page_id` is the id of your desired page
Its because `the_permalink();` echos directly but

> get_permalink();

will return you a value that you have to echo manually. That is the reason why your link is not being printed.

Hope that helps, try it please.

Comment: HI and thanks for help.
Is not the complete solution for my issue but I can say that is a step forward to succes. Thanks.

If you check my homepage now:

http://gianfabiopezzolla.com/centocelleonline.it

all of three box goes on the same page (I NEGOZI); Instead, I want that the first box goes to 'I NEGOZI'; the second box goes to 'second-page'; the third box goes to 'third-page'. 

Il try to insert the ID in:

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(37); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

but I commit some mistake that I don't know to fix. thanks for help and disposability.

Comment: try different page id for different thumbnails. Don't post the same ID. If you post the same `$page_id` it is obvious that it will redirect to the same page . 
If you want to put different page id dynamically you have to use wordpress loop else you have to put different page id manually . Try it manually if its working and you are not satisfied try using a loop . Happy Coding.